# How can I write the output stream of SDDP.jl into an excel file?

Tags: dynamic-programming, julia, multi-stage, stochastic-dual-dynamic-programming

I am using [SDDP.jl](https://github.com/odow/SDDP.jl) for my research project in which I am developing a state-of-the-art actor critic algorithm which I am going to benchmark with SDDP but for it I need to plot graphs which require data to be in excel or csv form.

Is there a way to transfer the output stream into excel file?

I have searched the whole internet but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `log_file` keyword argument to `train`: https://odow.github.io/SDDP.jl/stable/apireference/#SDDP.train

Or, after training, use the `write_log_to_csv` function: https://odow.github.io/SDDP.jl/stable/apireference/#SDDP.write_log_to_csv

p.s., in future, feel free to ask SDDP.jl-related questions by opening an issue: https://github.com/odow/SDDP.jl/issues.

Comment: thankyou very much dear Oscar, the issue has been resolved